# Access a PartialView's Model in a View which implements that PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can you access a PartialView's model, in a View which implements that PartialView?

I'm thinking something along the lines of: `Page.FindControl("PartialView-name").Model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial view (.ascx) is included from a view (.aspx). If this partial is strongly typed you pass the model from the view so you already have access to it:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/SomePartial.ascx", SomeModel); %>
```

Comment: Bad design on my side of things, and too quick to turn to SO :)